# How to show the content of NSDictonary as key value pairs in a NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nstextfield

i'd like to know how i can print the contents of a NSDictonary of unknown size fully in a NSTextField? The output should look like this at the end:

Key1:  Value
Key2:  Value
Key3:  Value
.
.
.
KeyN:  Value

Comment: Show us what you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString new];
for (id key in myDictionary)
{
    [string appendFormat:@"%@: %@\n", key, myDictionary[key]];
}
// Delete last newline
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([string length]-1, 1)];
myTextField.text = mutableString;
```

Comment: Typo - `myDictionary[value]` should be `myDictionary[key]`.

Comment: worked very well, thanks a lot! Although I don't know why i got down voted for the question.